# Is it possible to combine (add) 2 hash SHA256 to 1 SHA256?

Tags: sha256, calculation

So if I hash these word with SHA256 I will have:

"a": CA978112CA1BBDCAFAC231B39A23DC4DA786EFF8147C4E72B9807785AFEE48BB

"b": 3E23E8160039594A33894F6564E1B1348BBD7A0088D42C4ACB73EEAED59C009D

So I'm thinking about a way, function, or calculation to find the hash of "ab" which is:

"ab": FB8E20FC2E4C3F248C60C39BD652F3C1347298BB977B8B4D5903B85055620603 (this is what I want to find out of 2 hashes: "a" and "b")

"ba": 970F519C2CADBCEFB1E81694F904BC6229DD2A8300E98C6D0D4FC4BFCA584140 (if that calculation is correct that also means that I can perform it again to find "ba" hashed)

Comment: In other words, based on knowing only the two hashes, you want to derive the hash of "ab" and "ba"? I don't think that's possible, since the hash values tell you nothing about the original "a" and "b" values unless you are able to decode them (e.g. using rainbow tables).

Comment: As far as I know, each char of the string got some calculation and break into bits, those bits will form a hashed string, so is it possible to break 2 hashed "a" and "b" string into bits again and add them to "ab" bits and form it into a hashed string?

Comment: It's still not really clear what you're asking for. You can certainly hash any string or binary data, even one that is itself a hash. You can also concatenate two strings (or binary data) and hash them again. If you intend to derive the original data that yielded a given hash value, though, the answer is generally "no".

Comment: In short, let's call:
"HashA"
"HashB"
"HashAB"
I just want to know if there's a way to perform this calculation: HashA + HashB -> HashAB, and what I want in the result is HashAB (which if I hash SHA256 the word "ab" I will get the same as the result)

Comment: There is no practical way to combine Hash(A) and Hash(B) to get Hash(AB).

Comment: What do you think will be the best method to attack 64 digit password containing 36 possible characters (0->9 a->z [lower case]) by knowing its hash value ?

Comment: [What are rainbow tables and how are they used?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/379/what-are-rainbow-tables-and-how-are-they-used)

Comment: How about, I know the original "b" and don't know the original "a" but I know its length, can there be a way to combine Hash(a) and the "b" to get Hash(ab) ?

Comment: To get Hash(ab), you must know the original values of both a and b.